# Error when installing RestKit without CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, restkit

I'm new to RestKit and I'm trying to add it to my existing iOS Project - following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial).

After installing it as a Git submodule (I'm not using CocoaPods as I already have multiple plugins manually setup) and adding the linker flags, search paths, I'm not able to build it.

Nothing appears in the Issue Navigator, but on the Report navigator I get these errors:

```
(Check Dependencies)
The file "Pods-RestKit.debug.xconfig" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.

(Run custom shell script 'Check Pods Manifest.lock')
Diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
Diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
The sandbox is not in synch with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods Installation.
```

After this I tried to run 'pod install' in the subdirectory for RestKit, it installed with success, and when I then try to run the project, I get a 'normal' error that says:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-RestKit
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-RestKit is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Been stuck at this for a week so would really appreciate any assistance - I've tried researching extensively online but can't find any solution this this.

Comment: what do you opened xcworkspace or xcproject?

Comment: @RohitPradhan My iOS project is not using CocoaPods, so I don't have a xcworkspace for it, but for RestKit I dragged the xcproject into my iOS project to add it as a target.

Comment: Either upgrade so you use pods or don't use pods at all and just use got sub modules. The pods could include other config, not sure...

Comment: @Wain Could you explain a bit more what you meant? Do you mean that I remove all pods modules from the RestKit folder? I'm a newbie at this

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove it, you'd use git to install all of the sub module code. But upgrading would be a better option... You don't have to use pods for everything, still you already have should continue to work fine...

Comment: @Wain So I should try to do a 'pod install' on the main project? I already tried doing both a 'pod install' and 'pod upgrade' on the RestKit project but I just got the errors above.

Comment: Yes, though you need to undo what you previously did, add RestKit to the pod file (pod init if you need to) and then open the new workspace

Comment: @Wain Great thank you, that fixed it! :)